# Private image hosting (~50MB) to display on site behind a login

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image, web-hosting

I want to host around 50MB of photos that I can display on my site (Mongo + Node + React app). The site sits completely behind a login (native auth). How can I host these photos privately, so they can only be seen from the site, after having logged in?

Comment: Please use the internationally agreed abbreviation `MB` for *"megabyte"* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte If you use `mb` it looks like *"millibits"*.

Comment: Look at GridFS https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/storing-large-objects-and-files